# Translate imported class name to fully-qualified class name

Tags: php, namespaces

I've got the following code that handles object hydration, and then an example of a Resource descendant hydrating sub-resources using `array_map()`.

```
<?php
namespace foo\bar;

abstract class Resource {
    public static function hyrdrate($data) {
        if( ! key_exists('kind', $data) ) {
            throw new \Exception('Specified data does not have a "kind" attribute.');
        }
        list($type, $resource) = array_map('ucfirst', explode('#', $data['kind']));
        $class = sprintf('%s\%s\%s', __CLASS__, $type, $resource);
        if( ! class_exists($class) ) {
            throw new \Exception("Class $class does not exist for kind {$data['kind']}");
        }
        return new $class($data);
    }
}

namespace foo\bar\Resource\Compute;
use foo\bar\Resource;

class Instance extends Resource {
    public function getAdditionalResources() {
        return array_map(['foo\bar\Resource', 'hydrate'], $this->disks);
    }
}
```

The trouble is that in defining the callable for `array_map()` I've hard-coded the fully-qualified class name rather than just being able to use whatever the imported name `Resource` maps to. Yes, I can *technically* use `'self'` or `'parent'` or switch `array_map()` for a loop in this specific example, but in general knowing how to translate to a fully-qualified class name is something I'd like to have in my toolbox.

***Edit:*** The most general case I can come up with that illustrates what I'm looking for would be something like:

```
namespace a\b\c;
use a\b\SomeClass;
use d\e\f\MyReplacement as MyClass;

echo get_full_class_name('SomeClass'); // 'a\b\SomeClass'
echo get_full_class_name('MyClass');   // 'd\e\f\MyReplacement'
```

Comment: Which version, can you use `static::class`?

Comment: @TheAlpha that would return `foo\bar\Resource\Compute\Instance`

Comment: Yes, then what do you want?

Comment: @TheAlpha I've edited the question with a simplified example.

Comment: @TheAlpha you were close! Evidently `Resource::class` does the thing I want.

Comment: I thought you wanted the calling class because that inherits the Resource class so everything will be inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on IRC finally woke up and answered me!

@TheAlpha was close, but `static::class` will only return the name of the class inside of whose context the code is currently executing.

The correct answer is `ClassName::class`, eg:

```
namespace foo\bar\Resource\Compute;
use foo\bar\Resource;

echo Resource::class; // 'foo\bar\Resource'
```

Or:

```
namespace a\b\c;
use a\b\SomeClass;
use d\e\f\MyReplacement as MyClass;

echo SomeClass::class; // 'a\b\SomeClass'
echo MyClass:class;    // 'd\e\f\MyReplacement'
```